# In a PE-CE network, we would redistribute routes between BGP and IGP without `bgp redistribute-internal`. How does redistribution works?

Tags: bgp, eigrp, mpls-vpn, redistribution, igp

In a PE-CE network deployment on Cisco IOS/XE devices like -

```
   +-------------+                                                                                                                                              +-------------+
   |             |.1  198.51.13.0/24                                                                                                      198.51.56.0/24     .6 |             |
   |  R1-CUST-A  +--------------------------+                                                                                        +--------------------------+  R6-CUST-A  |
   |             | E0/1                     |                                                                                        |                      E0/1|             |
   +-------------+              +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------+              +-------------+
                                |           |                                                                                        |           |
                                |           |                                                                                        |           |
                                |       .3  | 3.3.3.3/32                            4.4.4.4/32                            5.5.5.5/32 | .5        |
                                |      +----+------------+                      +---------------+                       +------------+----+      |
                                |      |                 |.3   10.3.4.0/24    .4|               |.4     10.4.5.0/24   .5|                 |      |
                                |      |    R3-PE1       +----------------------+     R4-P      +-----------------------+    R5-PE2       |      |
                                |      |                 |E1/0              E1/0|               |E1/1               E1/1|                 |      |
                                |      +----+------------+                      +---------------+                       +------------+----+      |
                                |       .3  |E0/2                                                                               E0/2 | .5        |
                                |           |                                                                                        |           |
                                |           |                            SERVICE PROVIDER MPLS CORE NETWORK                          |           |
   +-------------+              +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------+              +-------------+
   |             | E0/2                     |                                                                                        |                       .6 |             |
   |  R2-CUST-Z  +--------------------------+                                                                                        +--------------------------+  R7-CUST-Z  |
   |             |.2  198.51.23.0/24                                                                                                      198.51.57.0/24    E0/2|             |
   +-------------+                                                                                                                                              +-------------+
```

R3-PE1 and R5-PE2 are Provider Edge routers. R4-P is a Provider Intermediate Router.
R1-CUST-A and R6-CUST-A are 'Customer A' router.
R2-CUST-B and R7-CUST-B are 'Customer B' router.

In this MPLS-L3-VPN topology, to provide connectivity between customer routers, say R1-CUST-A and R6-CUST-A, we would redistribute the routes between BGP and IGP (EIGRP/OSPF) on provider edge routers (R3-PE1 and R5-PE2).

Configuration on R3-PE1 is -

BGP

```
router bgp 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 bgp log-neighbor-changes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 no bgp default ipv4-unicast                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 neighbor 5.5.5.5 remote-as 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 neighbor 5.5.5.5 update-source Loopback0                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 !                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 address-family ipv4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 exit-address-family                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 !                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 address-family vpnv4
  neighbor 5.5.5.5 activate
  neighbor 5.5.5.5 send-community extended
  neighbor 5.5.5.5 next-hop-self
 exit-address-family
 address-family ipv4 vrf CUST-A
  redistribute eigrp 65001
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf CUST-Z
  redistribute eigrp 65026
 exit-address-family
```

EIGRP

```
router eigrp CUST-A                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 !                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 address-family ipv4 unicast vrf CUST-A autonomous-system 65001                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  !
  topology base
   redistribute bgp 1 metric 1500 100 255 1 1500
  exit-af-topology
  network 198.51.13.3 0.0.0.0
 exit-address-family
router eigrp CUST-Z
 !
 address-family ipv4 unicast vrf CUST-Z autonomous-system 65026
  !
  topology base
   redistribute bgp 1 metric 1500 100 255 1 1500
  exit-af-topology
  network 198.51.23.3 0.0.0.0
 exit-address-family
```

Configuration on R6-PE2 is -
BGP

```
router bgp 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 bgp log-neighbor-changes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 no bgp default ipv4-unicast                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 remote-as 1
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 update-source Loopback0
 !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family vpnv4
  neighbor 3.3.3.3 activate
  neighbor 3.3.3.3 send-community extended
  neighbor 3.3.3.3 next-hop-self
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf CUST-A
  redistribute eigrp 65001
 exit-address-family
 address-family ipv4 vrf CUST-Z
  redistribute eigrp 65026
 exit-address-family
```

EIGRP

```
router eigrp CUST-Z
 !
 address-family ipv4 unicast vrf CUST-Z autonomous-system 65026
  !
  topology base
   redistribute bgp 1 metric 1500 100 255 1 1500
  exit-af-topology
  network 198.51.57.5 0.0.0.0
 exit-address-family
router eigrp CUST-A
 !
 address-family ipv4 unicast vrf CUST-A autonomous-system 65001
  !
  topology base
   redistribute bgp 1 metric 1500 100 255 1 1500
  exit-af-topology
  network 198.51.56.5 0.0.0.0
 exit-address-family
```

If you observer we have NOT configured `bgp redistribute-internal` under the BGP configuration.
And I have read that the command `bgp redistribute-internal` is needed to be configured under BGP configuration so that BGP routes can be redistributed onto IGP protocol.
However, in this scenario even without the command `bgp redistribute-internal` redistribution of BGP routes into IGP(EIGRP) works. How is this possible?

Comment: Is this Cisco? Juniper? Which IOS version?
I found an article of Juniper that might be related:
https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junose15.1/topics/reference/command-summary/bgp-redistribute-internal.html

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear.
This question is related to Cisco IOS/XE configuration.

Comment: Is the following assumption correct? The routes you observe being redistributed on the PE into the IGP between PE and CE, they are *not* prefixes your would find in the core as  iBGP prefixes,  but theye are per-VRF IPv4 prefixes the PE extracts from the VPNv4 prefixes learned from the remote PE (or Route Reflector). This might explain why it works:  the PE is not redistributing iBGP ipv4 prefixes, but what it extracts from the given VRF's VPNv4 prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

From:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_bgp/command/irg-cr-book/bgp-a1.html?bookSearch=true#wp4270480859

> Command Default In releases prior to Cisco IOS Release 15.1(2)S,
> 15.2(1)T, and Cisco IOS XE 3.3S, in the IPv4 VRF and IPv6 VRF address families, IBGP routes are not redistributed into IGPs

I assume you have this:

> Beginning with Cisco IOS Release 15.1(2)S, 15.2(1)T, and Cisco IOS XE
> 3.3S, in the IPv4 VRF and IPv6 VRF address families, IBGP routes are redistributed into IGPs.